# Stacking 2-D arrays numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Lets say that `t` is a 2-D Numpy array of dimensions `(30,5)` (or in actuality, `(1,30,5)`) and `x` is also a Numpy array of shape `(1000, 5)`. I am trying to turn the 2-D data in x into 3-D data with each matrix in the new array being 30 (consecutive) of the 1000 rows in `x`. When you use `np.vstack` on the tuple of `t` and `x[:30]`, or

```
t = np.vstack((t, x[:30]))
```

the shape of my output is `(60,5)`, but I want it to be `(2, 30, 5)`. How do I do this?

UPDATE: I tried the suggestion by dkv, implementing with:

```
t = np.random.rand(1,30,5)
for i, n in zip(x_data, np.arange(len(x_data))):
    l = len(x_data) - 29
    if n < l:
        t = np.vstack((t,x_data[n:n+30].reshape(1,30,5)))

t = np.delete(t, 0)
print(t[:2], t.shape)


>>> [ 0.38009933  0.82223491]
>>> (1691249,)
```

Now it is one dimensional. Any thoughts?

Comment: `t.reshape(2, 30, 5)`?

Comment: Note that (30,5) and (1,30,5) are different shapes. (30,5) is a matrix with 30 rows, 5 columns. (1,30,5) looks like a 30x5 horizontal plane

Comment: You're using np.delete() incorrectly. Try printing t.shape before that line to see that it's the right shape.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. One is

```
np.r_['0,3,1', t, x[:30]]
```

`r_` is sort of a "universal concatenator". The first argument in this case instructs it to concatenate along axis no 0, to make array arguments 3d and to pad dimensions if necessary in such a way that the orignally zeroth axis becomes axis number one in the padded array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reshape your x[:30] slice to match the dimensions of t so that you're actually stacking them in the correct dimension.

```
t = np.ones((1,30,5))
x = np.ones((1000,5))
out = np.vstack((t, x[:30].reshape(1,30,5)))
out.shape
>>> (2L, 30L, 5L)
```